# Set post terms on post publish

Tags: taxonomy, terms, publish

I am trying to set post terms on the post, when it is puublished

I use following code but is doesn't work

```
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'oj_publish_post');
function oj_publish_post($post_id) {
  $taxonomy = 'category';
  $term_id = array(8);
  $term_id = array_map('intval', $term_id);    
  wp_set_post_terms( $post_id ,$term_id, $taxonomy,true);
}
```

But, when I pass the id of the post manually
i.e instead of using post_id. I use 773 it works

```
   add_action('pending_to_publish', 'oj_publish_post');
    function oj_publish_post($post_id) {
      $taxonomy = 'category';
      $term_id = array(8);
      $term_id = array_map('intval', $term_id);    
      wp_set_post_terms( 773 ,$term_id, $taxonomy,true);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument from `pending_to_publish` action, `$post_id` in your case, is not ID but array (callback to publish).

I think it would be better to use the `publish_post` action, that way `$post_id` will actualy be the post id.

Also this is a very general action so if you have multiple post types it would be wise to check if the current post type is the actual one you want to add the term to

**Edited answer**

Or in your case you can pass the post id as following

```
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'oj_publish_post');
function oj_publish_post($post) {
  $taxonomy = 'category';
  $term_id = array(8);
  $term_id = array_map('intval', $term_id);    
  wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID ,$term_id, $taxonomy,true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply .. Yep you are right.. but isn't it Object instead of array..   I am using $post->ID   works now..  thanks for the alternate method too - publish_post